# ./manage.py shell > update_db.py deletes the contents of the file

Tags: python, django

In my Django project I have a couple of methods I manually call time to time for testing purposes, but lately something strange is happening. Whenever I try to run a function in the context of my Django app:

```
./manage.py shell > scraper/update_db.py
```

it overwrites the contents of "update_db.py" with this:

```
>>>
```

I've tried creating arbitrary python files with simple print statements, but same happens to all of them. My current update_db.py looks like this:

```
def consistency_check():
    # removed my code with print statement
    print('Hello')

consistency_check()
```

Any ideas what is happening? I guess it's worth mentioning that I'm working in Pycharm and when I import my functions in python console, it's working just fine in there:

```
from scraper import update_db
update_db.consistency_check()
# Runs smoothly
```

**Update:**
Contents of manage.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "Enigma.settings")
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

Comment: What is the content of  `manage.py`?

Comment: I expect you want `<` rather than `>`

Comment: @DanielRoseman Can't believe I missed it, thank you!

Comment: @G.M remember to mark the answer as correct, some people motivate us to continue contributing our bit ;)

Comment: @BrianOcampo Your answer is correct but not entirely complete. As Daniel Roseman has mentioned I've mixed up the signs. Include his comment in your answer and I'll gladly accept it :) Because this line: ./manage.py shell < scraper/update_db.py is the solution I was looking for.

Comment: Jajaja ok, I think it's correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
./manage.py shell > scraper/update_db.py
```

When you execute this command referencing the file directly using the diple, what you are doing is assigning the output of the command "./manage.py shell" to the file "scraper / update_db.py" and that is why your code is replaced

For what you want to do, you should do the following:

```
./manage.py shell < scraper/update_db.py
```

**Updated:**

Comment: I expect you want < rather than > by @Daniel Roseman

Comment: "assigning the output" isn't *quite* right -- it implies that the output is collected, and *then* placed in the file. Rather, the file is truncated and opened for write *before* `manage.py` is started, and the program is run with its output configured to go directly to that now-empty file.